# Garbage collection causes lag on connected sockets (NodeJS Server)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, garbage-collection

I am hosting a game website on Heroku that runs on a NodeJS Server. Clients are connected via sockets using the package [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Once in a while when the garbage collection cycle is triggered, connected clients would experience severe lag and often, disconnections. This is experienced by the clients through delayed incoming chat and delayed inputs to the game.

When I look into the logs, I find error messages relating to the Garbage Collection. Please see the attached logs below. When these GC events happen, sometimes it causes massive memory spikes to the point where the app would exceed it's allowed 0.5GB RAM and would be killed by Heroku. Lately however, the memory spikes don't occur as often, but the severe lag on the client side still happens around once or twice a day.

One aspect of the lag is through the chat. When a user types a message through "All Chat" (and any chat channel), the server currently `console.log()`'s it to the standard out. I happened to be watching the logs live one time during a spike event and noticed that chat being outputted to the terminal was in real time with no delay, however clients (I was also on the website myself as a client) received these messages in a very delayed fashion.

I have found online a NodeJS bug (that I think was fixed) that would cause severe lag when too much was being `console.log`ed to the screen so I ran a stress test by sending 1000 messages from the client per second, for a minute. I could not reproduce the spike.

I have read many guides on finding memory leaks, inspecting the stack etc. but I'm very unsure how to run these tests on a live Heroku server. I have suspicions that my game objects on closing, are not being immediately cleared out and are all being cleared at once, causing the memory spikes, but I am not confident. I don't know how to best debug this. It is also difficult for me to catch this happening live as it only happens when more than 30+ people are logged in (Doesn't happen often as this is still a fairly small site).

The error messages include references to the `circular-json` module I use, and I also suspect that this may be causing infinite callbacks on itself somehow and not clearing out correctly, but I am not sure.

For reference, here is a copy of the source code: [LINK](https://github.com/vck3000/ProAvalon)

Here is a snippet of the memory when a spike happens:
[Memory spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT4UD.png)

Crash log 1: [HERE](https://pastebin.com/w5GyKXbZ)

Crash log 2: [HERE](https://pastebin.com/Hc7icgHH)

Is there a way I can simulate sockets or simulate the live server's environment (i.e. connected clients) locally?

Any advice on how to approach or debug this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to consider is that console.log will increase memory usage. If you are logging verbosely with large amounts of data this can accumulate. Looking quickly at the log, it seems you are running out of memory? This would mean the app starts writing to disk which is slower and will also run garbage collection spiking CPU.

This could mean a memory-leak due to resources not being killed/closed and simply accumulating. Debugging this can be a PITA.

Node uses 1.5GB to keep long-live objects around. Seems like you on a 500mb container so best to configure the web app to start like:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 server.js
```

While you need to get to the bottom of the leak, you can also increase availability by running more than one worker and also more than one node instance and use [socket.io-redis](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) to keep the instance is in sync. I highly recommend this route.

[Some helpful content on Nodejs memory on Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-memory-use)

You can also spin up multiple connections via node script to interact with your local dev server using [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) and monitor the memory locally and add logging to ensure connections are being closed correctly etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I wasn't aware of the 1.5GB default RAM setting by NodeJS, goes to show that I should've read that Heroku NodeJS Memory page fully! I will test with the suggested configuration.

Running multiple synchronised servers is definitely one of my long term goals but I don't know enough to go about doing it just yet. Thank you for pointing me in that direction, I will look into it!

Using a node script to simulate multiple sockets sounds like a great idea. I will test using that and see if I can hunt down a memory leak. 

Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: No prob. Have just gone through all of the above for a pretty chatty RTS'ish game that used sockets and clustering as above.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up managing to track my "memory leak" down. It turns out I was saving the games (in JSONified strings) to the database too frequently and the server/database couldn't keep up. I've reduced the frequency of game saves and I haven't had any issues.

The tips provided by Samuel were very helpful too.